# Upload an app free and paid

Tags: android, google-play, android-inapp-purchase

Hello I am new to Android. With  my effort I have created an application for  device security. So I'm ready to upload my app to the *Play Store* but I want one app to be **free** and another one, **paid**. I can't understand how to make this with the same code.

And one more question. Is it allowed for a user to share the paid application over Bluetooth or in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `Android Flavors and Build Variants`.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: I am OK with that...can you please clarify my doubt that when my paid app shared through device to device from Bluetooth or anything should My app get paid?

Comment: @miningian I'm not sure if there is any way to protect your app from being shared, especially on rooted phones.

Answer (score 0):

JoJo Narte's answer is right and it is the most efficient solution.

As an alternative though, you could have two separate apps, let's say "MyAwesomeSecurityApp" and "MyAwesomeSecurityAppPro" and upload them both to *Play Store*. The first one will be free and the second one paid.

Keep in mind that having separate apps has it's pros and it's cons.As a con example, everytime you want to make a change you would have to do it twice.Once for each app. This is why i said that Jojo's answer is more efficient.

Comment: I am OK with that...can you please clarify my doubt that  when my paid app shared through device to device from Bluetooth or anything should My app get paid?